# SQL Multiple IN statements on one column

Tags: sql

Okay, I'm using WordPress, but this pertains to the SQL side.

I have a query in which I need to filter out posts using three different categories, but they're all terms in the post.

For example:

In my three categories, I select the following: `(Academia,Webdevelopment)` `(Fulltime,Parttime)` `(Earlycareer)`.

Now what I want to do is make sure when I query that the post has AT LEAST ONE of each of those terms.

**CORRECT RESULT:** A post with tags `Academia, Fulltime, Earlycareer`

**INCORRECT RESULT:** A post with tags `Academia, Earlycareer` (doesn't have fulltime or parttime)

Currently, my query looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE
(
$wpdb->terms.slug IN (list of selected from category 1) AND
$wpdb->terms.slug IN (list of selected from category 2) AND
$wpdb->terms.slug IN (list of selected from category 3)
)
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'jobtype' AND .......
```

When using this query, it returns no results when I select across the different categories (that is, I can choose 4 things from category 1 and it has results, but I can't choose anything from category 2 or 3. And vice versa)

I'm not sure if this is something to do with using `IN` more than once on the same column.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The query you wrote should match your CORRECT/INCORRECT results. I don't get what you mean with `select across the different categories`

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be correct. There is no any limitations in SQL about using IN for the same column miltimple times.

But ensure that you don't have any NULL values in your `list of selected from category 1/2/3` queries. Even single NULL value in these lists will give NULL as a result of whole 'WHERE' condition and you will get nothing as a result.

If this won't help then it must be WordPress issue.